# linear map of linear in/dependent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

L a linear map of $\mathbb{R}^m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

1)Does a linear map of two linear dependent vectors $\underline{x}$,$\underline{y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ to two linear independent vectors $\underline{u}$,$\underline{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ exist/is possible?


2)a)Does a linear map of two linear independent vectors $\underline{x}$,$\underline{y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ to two linear dependent vectors $\underline{u}$,$\underline{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ exist/is possible?

b)And if it is what are the consequences for $ker(L)$?


1)No, because if two vectors are dependent:

 $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}$, 

so that:  $k\underline{x}=\underline{y}$

and a linear map to two is linear dependent vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^n$is only possible by two vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^m$.


2)a)Yes, f.ex.: $f:\mathbb{R}^3 -> \mathbb{R}^2$,

with $f(x,y,z)^T = (x, y-z)^T$ for $(0,1,0)^T$ and $(0,0,1)^T$.

b)with the rank-nullity theorem:

$ dim V - dim (im T)= dim (ker T)$

$3 - 2 = 1 = dim (ker T)$ in the example

My questions are:

Is my explication for 1) & 2) sufficient?and if not how can I improve it?

Is 2)b) I don't really know how to interprete that...

Comment: I'd like to suggest the following improvements for your MathJax code: use `\to` or `\rightarrow` for an arrow $\to$, and use `\dim` for $\dim$, `\ker` for $\ker$, and `\operatorname{im}` for $\operatorname{im}$ (these expressions should be upright). [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with LaTeX, and [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to use Markdown formatting.

Comment: Your questions (1) and (2)(a) look identical...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

I'd explain (1) as follows, applying *explicitly* a linear map:

$$x,y\in\Bbb R^m\;,\;\;a\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;T\;\text{a linear map}\;,\; x=ay\implies Tx= T(ay)=aTy$$

You don't need to worry about (2)-(b) since (1)=(2)-(a) cannot be.

**Edit:** After the correction to (2)-(a): the zero map is a trivial example of this possibility, and in general, if

$$x,y\in\Bbb R^m\;,\;a\in\Bbb R\;\wedge\;Ty=aTx=T(ax)\implies T(y-ax)=0\implies \ker T\neq 0$$

Comment: I made a mistake in 2)a) it should be the linear map of 2 independent vectors to 2 dependent vectors...

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems you get the idea.

To improve, introduce a letter for the linear map we are talking about, say, $T$.
Then you can write like $k\,T(x)=T(kx)=T(y)$.

For 2b, if $k\,T(x)=T(y)$ then $kx-y\in\ker T$.